# How do I prevent Office UI Fabric React PeoplePicker results dismissing on scroll

Tags: reactjs, spfx, office-ui-fabric, peoplepicker

I am building an SPXF webpart which uses the Office UI Fabric React PeoplePicker to show people results, however I've noticed the results Callout is disappearing on scroll which is a particular issue on mobile where real estate is limited (e.g. when keyboard takes up half the screen and you want to scroll results).

I notice that the Callout component has the preventDismissOnScroll property which would appear to be what I need, however can I access this from the PeoplePicker?

```
<PeoplePicker
     context={this.props.context}    
     titleText=""    
     personSelectionLimit={1}    
     groupName={""}   
     showtooltip={false}    
     isRequired={true}    
     disabled={false}    
     ensureUser={true}    
     selectedItems={this._getPeoplePickerItems}                   
     // ** access Callout props for  preventDismissOnScroll={true} ?
     />
```

Or are there other solutions to this issue?

SPFx 1.8 | Office fabric React 6.156.0

Comment: I've just come across this which appears to refer to the same issue albeit with TagPicker: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/10435 - by the look of it it seems a resolution might be a fair bit off.

Answer (score 1):

You can access Callout props by using `pickerCalloutProps`. The `preventDismissOnScroll` is deprecated, but you can use `preventDismissOnEvent`.

```
<PeoplePicker
     ...
     pickerCalloutProps={{ preventDismissOnEvent }}
/>
```